# What is the trick for the Taylor series of $\dfrac{e^x}{1+x}$

Tags: taylor-expansion

Thanks for above comments. Post here is higly edited:

I know that :
$$e^x = \sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac{x^k}{k!} + o(x^n)$$
$$\dfrac{1}{1+x} = \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i x^i + o(x^n)$$

Thus:
$$ \dfrac{e^x}{1+x} = \sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac{x^k}{k!}\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i x^i  + o(x^n)$$

Using the Cauchy product thanks to the comments and answers of this question:
$$ \dfrac{e^x}{1+x} = \sum_{k=0}^n c_i x^k + o(x^n)$$
with $$c_i = \sum_{i=0}^{k} \dfrac{(-1)^{k-i}}{i!}$$.

Is this okay ? Is it a definitive form or can I go further in the developpement ?

Comment: make sure with a double sum you use a different index and sum using the index otherwise it gets very confusing

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Cauchy_product_of_two_power_series

Comment: Have you tried simplifying the first few values for $n$ and looked for a pattern?

Comment: All your summations are wrong. Every time a $k$ is required, you have used $n$ instead. (Also you should use two different variables for the final sum, as @HenryLee suggests.)

Comment: You use working on the generating function of [OEIS sequence A182386](https://oeis.org/A182386). whose entry has more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The secret hier is to use **different** summation indices in the sums:
$$\begin{align}
 \dfrac{e^x}{1+x} &= \sum_{i=0}^\infty \dfrac{x^i}{i!}\sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^jx^j\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^\infty(-1)^j \frac{x^{i+j}}{i!}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{(-1)^{n-i}}{i!}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: The downvoter is welcome to express his/her suggestions for improving the answer.

Comment: Welcome to the club of victims of mysterious downvoters !

Comment: Thanks @user for sharing the secret of Cauchy's product =)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for above comments. I edit :

I know that :
$$e^x = \sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac{x^k}{k!} + o(x^n)$$
$$\dfrac{1}{1+x} = \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i x^i + o(x^n)$$

Thus:
$$ \dfrac{e^x}{1+x} = \sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac{x^k}{k!}\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i x^i  + o(x^n)$$
Using the Cauchy product:
$$ \dfrac{e^x}{1+x} = \sum_{k=0}^n c_i x^k + o(x^n)$$
with $$c_i = \sum_{i=0}^{k} \dfrac{(-1)^{k-i}}{i!}$$.

Is this okay ? Is it a definitive form or can I go further in the developpement ?

Comment: It is correct except for the exponent of $(-1)$ in the last expression.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've edited the power of k to k-i

Comment: You could go further knowing the incomplete gamma function. But don't worry ! You will know about it soon. By the way $\to +1$.

Comment: You should edit the original post instead of putting corrections in an answer! Look for the word "edit"... click on it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simpler form. The number

$$n!\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$$ is known as the *subfactorial* of $n$.

Comment: Very interresing thanks. I'm glad to discover this number. Can i involve this number in my final developpement since i've the same power of -1 and i don't have the n! factor of my sum ?

Comment: @pomme: yes, you can.

Comment: the way to do it is not evident for me. Could you give more details ?

Comment: There is actually a simpler formula: $$
\left\lfloor {\frac{{n! + 1}}{e}} \right\rfloor .
$$

Comment: @Gary: quite right, I missed that. With rounding instead of floor, you can drop the $+1$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, you are right. I like to go with the floor function because the nearest integer notation $\left[ x \right]$ can be ambiguous (some people use it to denote the floor function).